# Non longer able to use googlefonts due to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Tags: fonts, cross-domain, subdomain

in my (sub)website I use google fonts thanks to

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Parisienne' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and it was working fine up to this morning. I have to admit that I performed small changes, but only on the css and php code.
Now, the fonts is no longer downloaded ! When checking with google tools I see this error :

> Font from origin 'http://fonts.gstatic.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://exemple1-mariage.o-liste.net' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

What can I do to solve this problem, please ?

Kind regards

Fabian

PS On my main website (o-liste.net) the Parisienne font appears without error.

Comment: I think that header would be served by Google. Do you need to register your site with Google to use their fonts? You may need to add your sub-site to a list of valid origin URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is still present if I use my laptop but when using my smartphone the font appears correctly !